# ImportError: No module named appJar

Tags: python, user-interface

I am very new to coding and was trying to create a gui using appJar in atom.
I followed the steps on the appJar website but whenever I run the code this is the message it gives:

> ImportError: No module named appJar

What do i do? Also am I using appJar correctly?

Comment: Did you install the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here for instructions on how to install the module: http://appjar.info/Install

You can try `sudo pip install appjar` or `sudo pip3 install appjar` if you're on Python 3

Answer (score 0):

if you have windows you can open cmd and type `pip install appjar` or if you are using a IDE that has terminal it is not important which operating system you are using. just type `pip install appjar` in IDE terminal.